# Calling an object field as ListTile attribute

Tags: dart, constants, flutter

I am trying to receive some data form a json file and then mapping these data into my "Json" class fields.

Is there a way to use the fields in my Json class as my ListTile attribute ?

for example:

```
Json json1 = new Json();
...
const ListTile(
                ....

                title: const Text (json1.fieldOne()),
...
```

so that the ListTile attributes can read from the new object's attributes instead of defining constant values to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` values in Dart are expressions that are resolved at compile-time. 
There is no way to use value created with `new X()` in a const context (like `title: const Text(...)`)

I don't know Flutter well, but I guess just not using `const` should work as well

```
new ListTile(
                ....

                title: new Text (json1.fieldOne()),
```

If this code is embedded in another `const` context, you need to replace `const` by `new` all the way up.

`const` is used in Flutter as much as possible for performance reasons, but if it's not possible, as in your case because the value isn't yet available at compile time, then just replace it with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was doing something wrong

changed `const ListView` to `new ListView` as well as all the attributes in it.